# Comparing the outputs of two SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm having some trouble with a complex SQL query, and I would appreciate any help. I've simplified the tables && names.

```
SCHEMA:   

  Business Account
    payment_account_id
    business_id

  Business Misc
    business_user_id
    business_id

  Payment Account
    business_user_id
    payment_account_id
```

I need a SQL query that takes all of the businesses that have more than one payment account, all of the business users that have more than one payment account, and gives me an overlap of when those payment accounts have the same id.

So far I've gotten:

```
business_with_multiple_accounts = 

select * 
from "Business Account" 
group by business_id 
having count(distinct payment_account_id) > 1;

users_with_multiple_accounts =

select * 
from "Payment Account" 
group by business_user_id 
having count(distinct payment_account_id) > 1;
```

I think I just need to compare these two outputs (but I could be wrong!) but I'm unsure of how to proceed. I've tried nesting the queries in various ways, as well as using the "Business Misc" table in a three-way-join.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Please keep going towards a [mcve]. PS What does "compare these two outputs" mean. You have two tables with ids--when does a row turn up in the result, based on what rows are in those tables?

Comment: Plz show sample input, and expected output !

Comment: Please describe the technical details by copying from this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9835

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
business_with_multiple_accounts = 
select * 
from business_acct
where 
      (Select Distinct count(*) 
       from 
         payment_acct  
         where payment_acct.payment_acct_id= business_acct.payment_acct_id
       )>1
group by business_id 

users_with_multiple_accounts =
select * 
from business_misc 
where 
      (Select Distinct count(*) 
       from 
         payment_acct  
         where payment_acct.business_user_id= business_misc.business_user_id
       )>1
group by business_user_id
```